# Android notifyDataSetChanged() only the last added item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `ListView` and its adapter class that extends `BaseAdapter`.

I want to animate a little custom partial that goes inside the listview.

I have the animation for the partial which is to slide from right to left - this works very good first time.

Within the method of the Adapter, similarly as shown, for brevity:

```
public View getView(){

    Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.transladar);
    an.reset();
    vi.startAnimation(an);
    return vi;
}
```

looks good, but when I add one more item  `chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` gets triggered which refreshes all my items and restarts the animation.

I only just want to animate the last item within the Adapter itself.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add public Boolean variable (`isFirstTime = true;`) and in your `getView()` check it like this

```
if(isFirstTime){
    Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.transladar);
    an.reset();
    vi.startAnimation(an);

   if(position == getCount()-1) isFirstTime =false;
}else{
  if(position == getCount()-1){
     Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.transladar);
    an.reset();
    vi.startAnimation(an);
   }

}
```

Note: this is fast solution I don't know if there other way.

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the convertview is null and then prepare the animation. Tested and works for me:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                R.layout.workshop_components_list_item, null);
    }

    Animation animation = null;
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    if (null == holder) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_listItemName);
        holder.position = position;
        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.components_list_item);
        animation.setDuration(500);
    }

    ListItem item = getItem(position);
    holder.name.setText(item.getName());

    if (null != animation) {
        convertView.startAnimation(animation);
        animation = null;
    }

    return convertView;
}
```